# Angular 7 filter array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following Angular component:

```
  private json: JsonResponseDTO;

  constructor(private dtoService: PoolDTOServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtoService.setJsonResponse();
    this.getPool();
  }

  getPool() {
    this.json = this.dtoService.jsonResponse;
  }
```

The `json` contains an element pools, that is an  array. This one should be filtered by name, which is typed in an input. (I don not show the HTML, since this is not relevant).
I want to be able to 'remove' my search criteria, so the initial approach is:

```
  private json: JsonResponseDTO;
private filterJson: JsonResponseDTO;

  constructor(private dtoService: PoolDTOServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtoService.setJsonResponse();
    this.getPool();
  }

  getPool() {
    this.json = this.dtoService.jsonResponse;
    this.filterJson = this.json;
  }

  filter(filterCriteria: String) {
    this.filterJson = this.json;
    this.filterJson.pools.filter((element) => element.name === filterCriteria);
  }
```

and then bind the `filterJson` to the HTML DOM.
Is there a cleaner way to do this?
I want to avoid requesting the new JSON each time the filtered name is 'removed', since the data is expensive in time to fetch.

Comment: Are you just want to know is this a fine way or not?

Comment: I want to know if someone sees a cleaner way, because copying an array seems not right to me

Comment: If you don't want to request new JSON then filter is the only option you can do.

Comment: here is many copying of json response. why it is so? try to use observable with behaviour subject in service. so when you need you can filter this at the component side.

Comment: the clean way i think is to add a get method on the backend that take filterCriteria as  parameter and try to add pagination

Comment: @FatehMohamed why would he want to run an extra service for something that can be handled in the client directly? I am sorry but I think it would be a waste of network bandwidth if the entire data can be easily cached in the client. But sure enough if the JSON is very big, it might not make sense to load it all at once in which case you will have to implement the logic elsewhere.

Comment: I dont want to use my network bandwith and also no pagination, beacuse the only criteria is a text that is applied to the name

Comment: yes my idea is about the case of a very big data, may be he doesn't need that in the beginning but who knows later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pipe for filtering it will be much cleaner, just add the pipe in front of *ngFor directive.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, field: string, input: string) {
    if (input !== undefined && input.length >= 2) {
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      if (typeof value[0] === 'string') {
        return value.filter(function(el: any) {
          return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        });
      }
      return value.filter(function(el: any) {
        return el[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
      });
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Add this pipe, and in HTML where ever you need to filter

```
<div *ngFor="let val of filterJson | filter: "filterCriteria""> </div>
```

from change detection and performance point of view, pipes are awesome. Hope this helps, all the best

Comment: @DhananjaiPai lol no, since the DOM needs to be rendered once the list is updated its much more economical to handle this via pipes, (Pipes are pure, managing change detection via same is much more easier)

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(filterCriteria: String) {
    this.filterJson = {...this.json, pools: pools.filter((element) => element.name === filterCriteria);
}
```

You could potentially write it a bit cleaner by using spread and changing the pools property as above.

I'm assuming you should keep a cached copy of the original 'this.json' for a case when the filters are reset.

Comment: yea, thats my primary concern, how to 'restore' the original when the filter is removed

Comment: Again, assuming you are using filterJson to display the pool in the UI and you want to get the original data back when filter is cleared, you can simply do this.filterJson = {...this.json} to revert back to the original response and have angular rerender