# How to filter data in Angular view based on user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I would like to display data in **Angular 7/8** based on user search parameters. Initially the view should be blank,but when the user inputs the search parameters and clicks the **Submit** button the view should be updated with the new/filtered information.

Desired approach: Empty **ArrayB** should be populated with the filtered data of **ArrayA**

Implementation:

```
ArrayA = [{id:1, Name:"Steve"},{id:2, Name:"Maureen"},{id:3, Name:"Damian"},{id:4, Name:"Dee"}];
ArrayB = [];
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form" [formGroup]="filterForm" >
            <label for="">ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="person_id" formControlName="person_id" id="person_id">
            <button type="submit" (click)="submit($event)">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" ngFor="let filteredArr of ArrayB">{{filteredArr.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click submit, the **ArrayA** should be filtered based on the ID provided by the user and pushed into **ArrayB** and the view updated with the new information.

```
    submit(event){
//Filter ArrayA and push to ArrayB
    }
```

If there is a better and much simpler way of achieving the same i will greatly appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 filter array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232387/angular-7-filter-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .filter() function to filter `arrayA` then you can store the generated result in `arrayB` and then bind this `arrayB` to your `html template`.
In  below example `id` can be considered as input coming from user and when he click on `submit` button you can fire this filter function to get `arrayB`.

Your html code can be like this:
   `<button (click)="clickHandler()">submit</button>`

Where `clickHandler()` will be the function where you'll write your filter logic.

```js
ArrayA = [{id:1, Name:"Steve"},{id:2, Name:"Maureen"},{id:3, Name:"Damian"},{id:4, Name:"Dee"}];


let id = 1;

arrayB = ArrayA.filter((item)=>{
    if(item.id == id)
      return item;
    else 
      return null;
})

console.log(arrayB);
```

Comment: how do i implement the binding part, my current implementation is generating an  `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` as arrayB is initially empty

Comment: here is my implementation: `<div class="col-12" ngFor="let filteredArr of ArrayB">{{filteredArr.name}}</div>`

Comment: @SteveGaita It is Name with N

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
let filteredUserID = this.form.get('person_id').value
this.ArrayB = this.ArrayA.filter(item => item.id == filteredUserID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
this.ArrayB = this.ArrayA.filter(item => item.id == this.filterForm.value.person_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to `filter` your array `arrayA` based on values of `formControlName person_id`

```js
this.ArrayB = this.ArrayA.filter(item => item.id == this.filterForm('person_id').value));
```